# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\project\dbconfig.php on line 22

Tags: insert, command

$sql = $pdodbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO complaint ('id', 'username', 'email', 'mobiletype', 'mobilemodel', 'mobilenumber', 'complaint')
VALUES ('$id', '$username', '$email', '$mobiletype', '$mobilemodel', '$mobilenumber', '$complaint')");

```
    $pdodbcon->execute([$id, $username, $email, $mobiletype, $mobilemodel, $mobilenumber, $complaint]);
```

Comment: please share some more info like design and datatypes of your table columns and variable types that you are passing it looks like that one of your variable type is not matching your table column type.

Comment: Your question contains very minimal info. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as you are new here.